# Eclipse variable error in Java time zone enum

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, timezone, syntax-error

I'm getting an error when I declare a final TimeZone tz variable in my time zone enum. I found the example for this enum at http://snipplr.com/view/23131/timezone-enum/, but Eclipse gives me a "syntax error on token tz" and I can't figure out why. I've reconfigured the code several ways but this seems to be the best and Eclipse doesn't like it.

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

public enum TimeZoneEnum {

    DEFAULT(TimeZone.getDefault()),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_12(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+12")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_11(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+11")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_10(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+10")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_9(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+9")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_8(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+8")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_7(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+7")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_6(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+6")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_5(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+5")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_4(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+4")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_3(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+3")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_2(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_1(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+1")),
    ETC_GMT_PLUS_0(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+0")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_1(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-1")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_2(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-2")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_3(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-3")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_4(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-4")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_5(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-5")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_6(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-6")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_7(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-7")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_8(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-8")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_9(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-9")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_10(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-10")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_11(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-11")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_12(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-12")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_13(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-13")),
    ETC_GMT_MINUS_14(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-14")),

    private final TimeZone tz;

    private TimeZoneEnum(final TimeZone tz) {
        this.tz = tz;
    }

    public final TimeZone getTimeZone() {
        return tz;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ETC_GMT_MINUS_14(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT-14"));
                                                    ^-- notice the semicolon here
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you so much, can't believe I missed that. +1